# Pager buttons not displaying but pager does in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, pager

For some reason my pager displays below my grid but not the buttons to navigate to the next, previous, first, or last pages. I know the pager is displayed because the rowList attribute is shown and I can choose how many entries to show.

This is the JQGrid declaration code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery("#Table").jqGrid({
      jsonReader: {
           root:"rows",
           page:"page",
           total:"total",
           records:"records",
           repeatitems:false,
           cell:"",
           id:"id",
           userdata:"userdata"
         },
      url:'project/selectTable/loadTableInfo.do',
      datatype:'json',
      colNames:['Name','Size','Delete'],
      colModel:[
      {name:'name',index:'name', sorttype:'text'}, 
      {name:'size',index:'size', sorttype:'int'},
      {name:'delete',index:'delete',width:20, stype:'select'}],
      pager:'#pager',
      rowNum:50,
      rowList:[10,25,50,75,100],
      viewrecords:true,
      autowidth:true,
      height:"auto",
      pgbuttons:true,
      pginput:true,
      loadComplete: function(){ 
        var ids = jQuery("#Table").getDataIDs(); 
        for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){ 
          var cl = ids[i]; 
          X = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='X' onclick=deleteRow("+cl+");>" 
          jQuery("#Table").setRowData(ids[i],{delete:X});
          }
      }, 
      caption:'Info'
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="gridContainer">
  <table id="Table"></table> 
  <div id="pager"></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I think you didnt linked css files.

Comment: The css file I did include was ui.jqgrid.css. Do you know what css file it should be? Thanks!

Comment: user1042031 means jQuery UI CSS and only jqGrid CSS. Look at [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file) for more details.

Comment: I am using both jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css and ui.jqgrid.css, and there are no pager buttons. I had switched to another theme after asking the question and the buttons showed, but after switching again they are gone.